# MVC Check if table is empty from Layout

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I want to check if a table is empty from the layoutpage, and if it's empty I want to remove the link in the navbar that goes to the Newsindex.

This is what I've got so far:

Model:

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int NID { get; set; }

    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Newstext { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }

    public bool Empty
    {
        get
        {
            return (NID == 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Newstext));
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@if (Model.Empty) 
{
    <li><a href="http://localhost:10075/#nyheter">Nyheter</a></li>
} 
else {

}
```

The problem now is that it can't read what `Model.Empty` is and if I put `@model SeikoConsulting.Models.News` in the top of `_Layout.cshtml` I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ImageSlider.Models.Gallery]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SeikoConsulting.Models.News'.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be putting that logic in your layout. Instead define a section in your layout that you can insert content into. So in your layout, do something like this using the [`RenderSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537886(v=vs.111).aspx) method:

```
@RenderSection("EmptyTableSection", false)
```

Then in your views, you can insert content into the layout like this:

```
@section EmptyTableSection {
    <li><a href="http://localhost:10075/#nyheter">Nyheter</a></li>
}
```

Comment: I updated the post because I wasn't very clear when I wrote it the first time. Anyway, I want the <li> in the navbar to be removed if the table is empty. So if there is no news it shouldn't be a link in the navmenu at all, where ever you are on the website. I don't think your way works where ever you are on the website.